# Insert Images to the Server with Progressbar

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, android-image

Alright, so I have 8 (Bitmap) images to be inserted in my database, through PHP,and I want to ask  the logic on how can I create a Progress Dialog, that is 0% - 100%. I cant show any code to you because I haven't   started it yet but  I think I should use `Asynctask` right?

Comment: here is a link for ur reference..! http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can upload image using multipart in Asynctask [See demo](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) put asynctask in **for loop** till total number of images that you want to upload